# javascript/jquery size and dimension of uploaded image file

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, image-size

I need to display the image size in kilobyte and the dimension (height, width) using javascript/jquery. I came across few similar posts, but none could help me. I have two set of codes, that work separately. I can't figure out how to put them together.

This is the html code:

```
<span id="preview"></span>
<input type="file" id="file" onchange="displayPreview(this.files);"/>
```

This piece of code checks for file size & previews the image:

```
function onFileLoad(e) { 
    $('#preview').append('<img src="'+e.target.result +'"/>');  
}
function displayPreview(files) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = onFileLoad;
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
    fileSize = Math.round(files[0].size/1024);
    alert("File size is "+fileSize+" kb");
}
```

This piece of code checks for file size:

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#file").change(function (e) {
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
        };
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```

Please help me to put these codes together and display both the size and dimension together.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All you have to do to use the two codes is to combine them in the `displayPreview` function. You can create the image object that will append to the `preview` and find it's size, width, and height all in the same function.

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
function displayPreview(files) {
   var file = files[0];//get file   
   var img = new Image();
   var sizeKB = file.size / 1024;
   img.onload = function() {
      $('#preview').append(img);
      alert("Size: " + sizeKB + "KB\nWidth: " + img.width + "\nHeight: " + img.height);
   }
   img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this

HTML

```
<span id="preview"></span>
<input type="file" id="file" />
```

JQUERY

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

function displayPreview(files) {
    var img = new Image(),
        fileSize = Math.round(files.size / 1024);

    img.onload = function () {
        var width = this.width,
            height = this.height,
            imgsrc = this.src;

        doSomething(fileSize, width, height, imgsrc); //call function

    };
    img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(files);
}

// Do what you want in this function
function doSomething(size, width, height, imgsrc) {
    $('#preview').append('<img src="' + imgsrc + '">');
    alert("Size=" + size);
    alert("Width=" + width + " height=" + height);


}
```

Both methods

Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/w4y75/
Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/w4y75/1/

Comment: Manish, I am not able to reproduce what the above code is expected to. Can you check it again? Actually, I had visited the link and tried it before posting my query here. Even when I copied the code as it is; it did not work. I am using latest versions of chrome and firefox.

Comment: @sridhar . Try the above code. hope it helps. or you can go for straker's version its good too

Comment: Th method posted by @Straker is good, but I figured out why the jsfiddle code was not working for me. It was a silly overlooking of this initialization ' $(window).load(function(){}); ' in the beginning.

Comment: the above code works when there is only one upload file element. What to do when there are many?

Comment: I figured the way to handle multiple upload file elements by calling same function with different element ids. `$("#filex").change(function() {
  var file = this.files[0];
  displayPreview(file);
 });` How do I reference ids inside the javascript file?

Comment: How do I find out which is the current/active ID? This line of code doesn't help `var $theid = $(this).attr("id");`

Comment: @sridhar You can use class instead of id for input file check here http://jsfiddle.net/code_snips/w4y75/2/

Comment: i dont know why your second JSFIDDLE is not loading.

Answer (score 1):

How to get image width and height using jquery

Find out the image width and height during image upload using jQuery

Size and dimension of upload image file

```
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
$("#myfile").change(function (e) {
    var file, img;
    if ((file = this.files[0])) {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = function () {
            var wid = this.width;
            var ht = this.height;

            alert(this.width + " " + this.height);
            alert(wid);
            alert(ht);
        };

        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(file);
    }
});
```