# Why i not get value of file.width and file.height Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I will get file.type and file.size but why i not get file.width and file.height value? See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k7s38z97/).

```
<input id="test" type="file"/>

<script>
  document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('change', function() {
    var file = this.files[0],
      img;
    if(file) {
      img = new Image();
      alert(file.type);
      alert(file.width);
      alert(file.height);
      alert(file.size);
    }
  });
</script>
```

How to get file.width and file.height value ?

Comment: Why would a 'file' have a width and height?  An image could, sure.  But a generic file?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

Comment: When user post a file, it is not immediatelly parsed to image data. You should use `FileReader` to get base64 URL and then convert it to image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript/jquery size and dimension of uploaded image file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19816705/javascript-jquery-size-and-dimension-of-uploaded-image-file)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695061/why-does-my-check-image-dimension-function-not-work-with-onchange-dom-javascript/40695175